# Overlying video frames using FFmpeg in c++

Tags: c++, opengl, ffmpeg, video-processing

I am trying to overlaying two videos using FFmpeg in c++. So I followed the FFmpeg page and followed this command in terminal.

```
$ ffmpeg -i Right.mov -i Left.mov -filter_complex "[0:v][1:v] overlay=0:0"  -c:a copy output.mov
```

I can implement this functionality through the terminal, but I am trying to achieve this functionality through codding.

```
typedef struct {
    AVFormatContext *fmt_ctx;
    int stream_idx;
    AVRational time_base;
    AVStream *video_stream;
    AVCodecContext *codec_ctx;
    AVCodecContext *pCodecCtxOrig;
    AVCodec *decoder;
    AVPacket *packet;
    AVFrame *av_frame;
    AVFrame *gl_frame;
    AVFrame *out_frame;
    AVStream *pStream;
    struct SwsContext *conv_ctx;
```

also, I show some example code, but I am not sure about it

https://ffmpeg.org/doxygen/2.1/doc_2examples_2filtering_video_8c-example.html

and 
https://code5.cn/so/c%2B%2B/2601062

```
AVFilterContext *buffersink_ctx;
AVFilterContext *buffersrc_ctx;
AVFilterGraph *filter_graph;
```

how can I implement this functionality in my code?

Answer (score 1):

A long time ago I wrote a program that used ffmpeg to decode videos and display them as OpenGL textures. You can download the code from
[my home page](http://members.ozemail.com.au/~laranzu/3d/GLFFPlay.tar)
Please be warned that this code is over ten years old and hasn't been maintained, so I cannot say that it still works. But nobody seems to have a better answer for you, so I hope this helps at least get you started.